# Rails Array In A String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an array in string format:

```
"["a", "b", "c"]"
```

However, I need this as an array like:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

How can I do this in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `eval('["a", "b", "c"]')`

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem.